# Xcode 11 open Jump to definition in assistant editor

Tags: xcode11

How to open Jump to definition in assistant editor window itself. It used to work in pre Xcode 11 but not in Xcode 11. In Xcode 11 when I click on Jump to definition it opens file in main editor window instead of assistant editor.

I did a search but can't find any solution.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't have searched very hard as even googling your title finds many references to it.  Anyway...

Option-click the menu entry, or just ctrl-option-cmd the word directly.

Comment: I'm using windows keyboard. I've tried all possible options but none works. If we forget the option-click and any other command options and go back where it used to work for me then I used to right click on the function name (See the screenshot) and from drop down click on Jump to Definition which used to open the def in same assistant editor window. It doesn't work in xCode 11 anymore. What has changed which caused it to stop working? How to get it back?

Comment: OK, to be clear these actually opens the definition in a second Editor window in the same tab, rather than the old assistant editor.  Have you done anything to disable multiple editor panes? I thought the option key was the same as the alt key on Windows?  If so, ctrl-option(alt)-cmd-J on the term will open definition in a second editor

Comment: On left side I've storyboard and on right I've assistant editor. In assistant editor when I click on Jump to definition it opens file on left side where I have storyboard. Funny thing is that sometimes it doesn't happen. I want the definition to open on right side window itself as it used to pre xCode 11. I can't remember changing any settings in xCode 11. I know how to open in second editor which I don't want. I want to open the definition in same window where I click on Jump to definition.